# Signal handler not being triggered from alarm() after timeout limit exceeded

Tags: c, signals, exec, alarm

I'd like to kill a child process if it exceeds the timeout limit, which is passed as an argument to the program in seconds.

In this example, I passed 3 as my timeout limit. The program here is `/bin/cat` without any additional arguments, so it should hang and `SIGALRM` should be triggered, but for some reason it's not triggering the `killChild()` function.

```
void killChild(int sig) {
    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
    kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Parse timeout arg
    int timeout = 0;
    if (argv[1] != NULL) {
        timeout = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    char program[] = "/bin/cat";

    // Create child process
    pid_t child = fork();


    if (child == 0) { // Child

        signal(SIGALRM, killChild);
        alarm(timeout); 

        printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        char* av[] = { program, NULL };

        execve(program, av, NULL);   
    } else {          // Parent

        printf("I'm the parent %d, my child is %d\n", getpid(), child);
        wait(NULL);
        alarm(0);    // Reset alarm if program executes within timeout limit
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: As per @alk's suggestion, the signal is being replaced so my only option is to keep it in the parent process, so I've modified the code to have the `alarm()` and `signal()` calls outside the child block.

Now the `killChild()` handler is being called, but there's one problem now in that the `getpid()` in `killChild()` is referring to the parent PID - how do I pass the child PID to `killChild()`?

```
signal(SIGALRM, killChild);
alarm(timeout);

if (child == 0) { // Child

    printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    char* av[] = { program, NULL };

    execve(program, av, NULL);   
} else {          // Parent

    printf("I'm the parent %d, my child is %d\n", getpid(), child);
    wait(NULL);
    alarm(0);    // Reset alarm if program executes within timeout limit
}
```

Comment: Maybe some code is missing, but I do not see where killChild() is called. And kill(getpid(),9) is just committing suicide. Sorry, I missed the handler.

Comment: @AlainMerigot `killChild()` is used as a signal handler

Comment: Note that using [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) with a null pointer for the environment is aconventional at best — I think it leads to undefined behaviour.  It isn't related to your current problem, though.

Comment: @woz: ... and is called by the OS on the process' reception of a signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install the signal handler for the child process and then call `execve()` which replaces completely the current program by the `exec`ed program. With this the signal handler is gone.

As you do not have control over what the `exec` process does only the parent can kill its child. So you want to install the signal handler for the parent and have it send a `SIGKILL` to the child.

Implementing this might be tricky as if would require the signal handler to know the child's PID.

There are several ways to do this.

Let's start with the complicated, but portable one. Here the signal handler does not kill the child but just sets a flag indicating it got called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


volatile sig_atomic_t f = 0;

/* to be set as handler for SIGALRM */
void sig_alarm(int unused)
{
  f = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  /* install signal handler here */
  ...

  /* fork/exec and set child_pid here */
  ...

  /* assuming to be in the parent from here */
  ...

  /* set alarm here */
  ...

  while (!f)
  {
    int status;        
    int result = waitpid(child_pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    if (-1 == result)
    {
      if (errno != EINTR)
      {
        perror("waitpid() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      continue;
    }
    else if (0 != result) /* child ended. */
    {
      /* Analyse status here to learn in detail if the child
         ended abnormally or normally and if the latter which
         exit code it returned (see W* marcos on man waitpid). */
      break; 
    }        

    sleep(1); /* busy waiting is not nice so sleep a bit */
  }

  if (f) /* sig-alarm handler was called */
  {
    if (-1 == kill(child_pid, SIGKILL))
    {
      perror("kill() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The quick and dirty solution which might not work an any system would be to defined the `child_pid` globally

```
volatile sig_atomic_t child_pid = 0;
```

and have the sig-alarm handler call

```
  kill(child_pid, SIGKILL)
```

The might not work as it is not clear if a `pid_t` fits into a `sig_atomic_t` on the platform the code is build for.

Also one may not use `printf()` and several other non-async-signal-save functions inside signal handlers. So calling `perror()` to indicate failure for example is a non-no.

Comment: That makes sense now. I've made your suggestions and added an addendum. The `killChild()` handler is being called now, but the problem is I'm not sure how to pass in the child PID to it. Any ideas?